# Find iOS simulator where specific app is installed?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a ton of iOS simulators on my machine and I know that one of them has a certain app installed on it that I want to run again (and I can't easily rebuild this app on a different simulator). How can I find which simulator has a certain app installed on it?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get what I wanted by running the following commands in Terminal:

```
cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
find . -name MyAppName.app
```

Then I went into the folder for the device with the app and opened `device.plist` which has name and iOS version of that simulator, which I could then open from the Simulator app Hardware > Device menu.